# Change password with mysql query in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, passport.js

I tried to change the password of a user with the ID: *273* but I tried everything and it is not working. I am planning on using this to manage my database over node.js

This is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'kitsune',
    //connectionLimit: 50,
    port: 3306 });

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

const iduser = 273; // ID
const newPassword = "dfgfgSD22";

// Change password to uppercased md5
var insertQuery = "UPDATE `penguins` SET `Password` = UPPER(MD5('" + newPassword + "') WHERE ID = " + iduser + ";"

connection.query(insertQuery, function(error, results, fields) {;
    console.log(insertQuery);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
  if (error) throw error;
});
module.exports = connection;
connection.end(); // End connection
```

It should update the password from the user with id *273* in md5 uppercase, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE `ID` = 273' at line 1

The query that gets printed out:

> UPDATE `penguins` SET `Password` = UPPER(MD5('dfgfgSD22') WHERE ID =
>   273;

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis `"') ) WHERE `

Comment: **DO NOT** use MD5 for passwords. At the **absolute least** use something like Bcrypt or Scrypt.

Comment: **WARNING**: You also **urgently** need to read up on [escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) before you create a [serious SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). Sorry about all the panic here, but if you're not careful you'll create a hacker access portal and not a user access system.

Comment: @Hackerman +1 that worked correct. Thank you & everyone else for the help. I will also check that link that you gave lleon to prevent questions.

Comment: @tadman that is correct, but this is a .js file that is `server-sided` and users will never be in touch with this.

Comment: You should also use https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries

Comment: I deleted that comment, it was a wrong library. Take a look a @tadman comments for a better help

Comment: Making excuses like that is how you develop lazy habits that can cost you huge in the future. Do it properly. It's not hard. It avoids bugs that can take a lot of time to eliminate. It saves time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have written

```
var insertQuery = "UPDATE `penguins` SET `Password` = UPPER(MD5('" + newPassword + "') WHERE ID = " + iduser + ";"
```

here

```
`Password` = UPPER(MD5('" + newPassword + "')
```

Now only one bracket is closing

```
`Password` = UPPER(MD5('" + newPassword + "'))
```

Replace following line

```
  var insertQuery = "UPDATE `penguins` SET `Password` = UPPER(MD5('" + newPassword + "')) WHERE ID = " + iduser + ";"
```